# Where is the best place to put the custom jquery and javascript in Zend Framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework

where is the best place to put the jquery and javascript scripts in zend framework?

shall i put every script in js file and append in the controller like :

**$this->view->headScript()->appendScript**

or to leave in the phtml page as is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it depends on your scripts, if your script is linked to your controller, you could include it in the `_init()` method of your controller.

I usually prefer to include my .js scripts inside my view (when they concern only one unique view) using `$this->jQuery()->addOnload()` for jQuery and:

```
<?php $this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/user-list.js') ?>
<?php $this->headScript()->captureStart() ?>
site = {
    baseUrl: "<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>"
};
<?php $this->headScript()->captureEnd() ?>
```

for js scripts.
As you can see in this second example, a **real advantage to use captureStart() is that you can use PHP to generate contents in your Javascript**. It can be pretty useful for translating a word for example.

Finally, `_initView()` method in your bootstrap is a good place to put web-site relative .js.

Answer (score 1):

- Javascript you need for the **entire site** you want to add during *bootstrap*, in a view setup or `initView` method.
- Javascript you need for some **controller**, you should append in the `init()` method of that controller.
- Javascript you only need for a certain **action**, you should append in that action.

This way the client never has to download more data/files than really needed.